# Excel formula for combining two IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got this formula in inputted which pulls out the value `=IF(LEN(LEFT($A2, SEARCH(".xyz", $A2)-1))<13, "Invalid", "")`

However I want to include this part of the formula `=IF(LEN(LEFT($A2, SEARCH(".twy", $A2)-1))<13, "Invalid", "")`

I tried adding OR after the first IF and combining both but it does not work. Any suggestion?

Below is the sample

| ID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `asldna.xyz` |  |
| `asd.twy` | Invalid |
| `asdjhhh.cyv` | Invalid |
| `asdhthen.xyz` |  |
| `asdh.xyz,asdh.cyv` | Invalid |

Comment: Are these options always three characters at the end just after the dot? Do you just want to know if the length before these two options occur is >=13?

Comment: No it is not. it is either 3 or 4 characters after the dot. However, as you can see one cell may contain 1 element of .xyz but also contain .cyv. In this case, it should show invalid.

Comment: Can you explain why you want the results you are showing in the samples? For example: Why is asdjhhh.cyv invalid? And why is asdhthen.xyz not invalid? The results don't seem to correspond with what you are doing in the formula. Another point; do you need to work with comma-seperated values? And if so, how do you want this to affect the results? I mean, if you are finding 'cyv' in the last sample, does the substring to the left of it needs to be from the start of the cell or from the comma?

Comment: Either way, how I would interpret your question is that you could try: `=IF(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(' xyz twy ', concat(' ', substring-after(., '.'), ' '))][string-length(substring-before(., '.'))<13]")),"","Invalid")` as an cse-entered formula from Excel 2013 onwards.

Comment: I will try this but it seems too difficult to comprehend for me. I will have a look at it definitely, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(LEN(LEFT($A2, SEARCH(".xyz", $A2)-1))<13, "Invalid", IF(LEN(LEFT($A2, SEARCH(".twy", $A2)-1))<13, "Invalid", ""))
```

Such that if the first if is not true and then the second if is not true the output is "".

Edit based on comment:
=IF(LEN(LEFT($A2, SEARCH(".xyz", $A2)-1))<13, "Invalid_1", IF(LEN(LEFT($A2, SEARCH(".twy", $A2)-1))<13, "Invalid_2", ""))

Comment: When I do this, it shows the invalid part correctly however the valid part indicates #VALUE!

Comment: @JoseJondoe well, if your original formulae don't function correctly then you have an issue to correct, all I did was add one to the other. Suggest you put "invalid_1" and "invalid_2" to identify which is or is not working.